# How are 3d images rendered in 2d space?

Tags: 3d

There was a similar question asked on this same site a few years ago ([How to transform a set of 3D vectors into a 2D plane, from a view point of another 3D vector?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164700/how-to-transform-a-set-of-3d-vectors-into-a-2d-plane-from-a-view-point-of-anoth)), but the answerer seemed to kind of jump into hard-to-follow math steps without an adequate explanation as to why he did what he did. I know I could have left a comment, but given the age of the answer, he may not be interested in posting a reply.

Comment: At the very least, provide a link to the other question that you're referring to. And please be more specific in your question, the title is *very broad*

Answer (score 0):

I have kind of an idea:

Imagine you're lying down and looking at  a box whose inside you can see from the outside. Also, imagine that this box is angled somewhat. You and the box are parallel to the ground. You pick an edge - called point A - and to an observer who can only see in two dimensions, the edge's location on a coordinate plane is the location of a point - which we'll call B - that you, the 3D observer, know is a point from which someone looking at the top of the box and who is also angled parallel to the ground can draw a line that connects to the edge.

The trick, then, is to find point B. And that's the point that the computer displays on screen.