# Calculating coordinates of a view plane

Tags: geometry, 3d

So I have a set of 3D points that I need to translate onto a 2D viewpoint. Now, while there do exist some very good explanations of how to do this on this site, all of them I have seen seem to neglect how you get the coordinates for the view plane.

[Shown in this wonderful answer to another question here as S,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164700/how-to-transform-a-set-of-3d-vectors-into-a-2d-plane-from-a-view-point-of-anoth/168584#168584) I am given the requirements that the coordinates must meet, but it seems to be assumed that I know where they should be placed. Given that the size of the viewpoint might change, having these as constants is not an option.

So my question is this: As shown in the above answer, how do I calculate $S_1$, $S_2$ and $S_2$? I really can't seem to get my head around the logical jump in the example from having a screen width of $800$ to $S_2$ being $(880,1040,400)$.

Comment: Please describe your setup in more detail. I’m having trouble figuring out exactly what it is that you’d like to know.

Comment: Ok. So in the image there is a square that represents everything the camera can see. For calculations, we need to know the top two corners and the bottom left one ($S_1, S_2, S_3$). I'm trying to figure out how to get where these corners are supposed to go. In the example that is given they just appear out of thin air.

Comment: They do appear out of thin air. Both the image plane placement and camera (focal) distance are arbitrary. The distance between the focal plane and screen determines the field of view, and the relative distances between the camera, screen and object determine the “zoom factor.” It’s easier in practice, I think, to position the camera and then find the equation of a plane a distance $h$ from the camera and perpendicular to the camera’s axis ($N$ in the cited writeup). The corners of the screen are easily computed from the screen dimensions.

Comment: N.B.: There’s a serious flaw in step 8 that will cause everything above the top of the screen to be reflected onto the screen. Also, the calculations are much more complicated than they need be. Once you’ve placed the camera, transform the coordinate system so that the camera is at the origin and points along the $z$-axis. The equation of the image plane is then simply $z=h$, the coordinates of the screen corners are trivial to compute, and the projection of points onto the screen is also very simple to compute.

Comment: Looks like the clipping has been corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates of the screen corners in [the cited write-up](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/168584/265466) do essentially “come out of nowhere.” Camera and screen placement are fundamental variables in setting up the view. Their relative placement determines, among other things, the field of view and zoom factor (focal length).

In practice, it might be easier to work backwards by first deciding on the camera’s line of sight. This establishes a line in your scene, which you can parameterize as $P+\lambda N$. $P$ is any point on the line (perhaps the camera’s position $C$, the midpoint of the screen $M$, or some other convenient reference point). $N$ is a unit vector parallel to the line that establishes its direction—the same normal (perpendicular) vector to the screen that’s calculated in step 6. To be consistent with the described method, it should point away from the scene, i.e., from the screen to the camera. You can always flip the signs of its components if you discover that it’s pointing the wrong way. Since $N$ has unit length, the parameter $\lambda$ measures signed distance from $P$ along this line.

Choose a point $M$ along this line to be the midpoint of the screen. How you do that is up to you. An equation of the plane through $M$ that’s perpendicular to the line of sight is $N\cdot((x,y,z)-M)=0$, which expands into $a_n(x-m_x)+b_n(y-m_y)+c_n(z-m_z)=0$. Now, you’ve got another choice to make: you have to specify a direction in the scene that corresponds to “up” on the screen. However you do this, you’ll end up with a vector $U$ that’s parallel to this plane with a direction that corresponds to “up” on screen. (One way is to locate a point $U'$ on the plane that’s directly “up” from $M$ and set $U=U'-M$.) Finding the corner points is simple from there.

Obviously, $S_1$ is halfway up the screen from $M$, so we’re going to have $M+\frac H2{U\over\|U\|}$, but we also need to go left from $M$. For that, we need a vector that represents right or left on the screen. We’ll go with right, since that’s where we need to go for $S_2$, anyway. Such a vector is given by the cross product $R=U\times N$. We’ve now got all of the necessary pieces to place the three corners of the screen: $$\begin{align}S_1 &= M + \frac H2{U\over\|U\|} - \frac W2{R\over\|R\|} \\ S_2 &= M+\frac H2{U\over\|U\|}+\frac W2{R\over\|R\|} \\ S_3 &= M-\frac H2{U\over\|U\|}-\frac W2{R\over\|R\|}.\end{align}$$ Note, by the way, that ${\overrightarrow{S_1S_2}\over\|\overrightarrow{S_1S_2}\|}={R\over\|R\|}$ and ${\overrightarrow{S_1S_3}\over\|\overrightarrow{S_1S_3}\|}=-{U\over\|U\|}$, so you’ve already got some of the values that you’ll need for computing the projection. That is to say, you don’t really need to compute $S_2$ and $S_3$ here.

Having gone through all of that, I must point out that these calculations and the ones for the projection itself are much simpler if you work in the camera’s coordinate system. Effectively, you “front load” the uglier parts of the computation into the world-to-camera transformation. In this sort of setup, the camera is at the origin, “up” is the positive $y$-axis and the camera points down the negative $z$-axis. The image plane (screen) is then simply $z=-h$ and the screen corners are at $S_1(-W/2,H/2,-h)$, $S_2(W/2,H/2,-h)$ and $S_3(-W/2,-H/2,-h)$. The projection of a point $A(x,y,z)$ onto this screen is simply $A'(-hx/z,-hy/z,-h)$, from which $(m,n)$ is easily found to be $\left(\frac W2-\frac hzx,\frac H2+\frac hzy\right)$. Clipping is also simple in this coordinate system. You can either check that $0\le m\le W$ and $0\le n\le H$ (which you can do if working in the world coordinate system, too) or check that $-W/2\le -hx/z\le W/2$ and $-H/2\le -hy/z\le H/2$, which is a lot simpler than computing all of those dot products and lengths in the world coordinate system.